# Can we show a text inside the placeholder other than an image in the FadeInImage widget?

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm wondering if I can only show a text other than an image in the placeholder of the FadiInImage widget.

```
AspectRatio(
  aspectRatio: 1 / 1,
  child: Container(
    decoration: BoxDecoration(
        color: getSecondaryColor,
        border: Border.all(color: getSecondaryColor),
        borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(1.5.h))),
    child: ClipRRect(
      borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(1.5.h)),
      child: FadeInImage(
          image: NetworkImage(category.categoryImage),
          placeholder: const AssetImage('assets/images/loading.jpeg'),
          fit: BoxFit.cover,
          placeholderFit: BoxFit.cover,
          alignment: Alignment.center,
          fadeInDuration: const Duration(milliseconds: 100),
          imageErrorBuilder: (context, error, stackTrace) {
            if (error is Exception) {
              return const SizedBox();
            }
            return const SizedBox();
          }),
    ),
  ),
);
```

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately the placeholder always requires an image.

You have two named constructors:

- [FadeInImage.memoryNetwork](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/FadeInImage/FadeInImage.assetNetwork.html) with a placeholder of type Uint8List.
- [FadeInImage.assetNetwork](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/FadeInImage/FadeInImage.memoryNetwork.html) with a placeholder of type String.

But all of them will try to create an ImageProvider from the provided placeholder.

As a workaround check the following example which is using the [transparent_image](https://pub.dev/packages/transparent_image) package (you may want to check the official [cookbook](https://docs.flutter.dev/cookbook/images/fading-in-images) sample)

```
Stack(
  children: <Widget>[
    const Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator()), // or any widget like a text
    Center(
      child: FadeInImage.memoryNetwork(
        placeholder: kTransparentImage,
        image: 'https://picsum.photos/250?image=9',
      ),
    ),
  ],
)
```

As an alternative you can create an image from a text (which I do not suggest if the first approach is working for you)

```
Future<Uint8List?> createMemoryImageFromText(String str) async {
    final builder = ParagraphBuilder(ParagraphStyle(fontStyle: FontStyle.normal));
    builder.addText(str);
    final paragraph = builder.build();
    paragraph.layout(const ParagraphConstraints(width: 100));

    final recorder = PictureRecorder();
    final newCanvas = Canvas(recorder);

    newCanvas.drawParagraph(paragraph, Offset.zero);

    final picture = recorder.endRecording();
    final res = await picture.toImage(100, 100);
    final data = await res.toByteData(format: ImageByteFormat.png);

    if (data != null) {
      return Uint8List.view(data.buffer);
    }

    return null;
  }
```

And then use can use it like this.

```
FutureBuilder(
  future: createMemoryImageFromText('Hello World'),
  builder: (context, snapshot) {
    if (snapshot.hasData && snapshot.data != null) {
      return FadeInImage(
        placeholder: MemoryImage(snapshot.data!),
        image: const NetworkImage('https://picsum.photos/250?image=9'),
      );
    }

    return const SizedBox.shrink();
  },
)
```